# How to get the original values from a navigation collection property in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

With Entity Framework Core, I need to check the original values of a navigation property inside my entity but i can't find a way to do it.

I'm able to read the original and the current values of the actual entity and also his reference property but the OriginalValue property is missing when I read the navigation property.

Here's what I been able to do so far.

```
var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<Book>()
                .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .ToList();

foreach (var entry in entries)
{   
   // read the entity current & original values 
   var currentTitleValue = entry.Property(x => x.Title).CurrentValue;
   var originalTitleValue = entry.Property(x => x.Title).OriginalValue;

   // read the reference object current & original values
   var promotionReferenceEntry = entry.Reference(x => x.Promotion);
   var currentPromotionPriceValue = promotionReferenceEntry.TargetEntry.Property(x => x.Price).CurrentValue;
   var originalPromotionPriceValue = promotionReferenceEntry.TargetEntry.Property(x => x.Price).OriginalValue;

   // read the navigation object current & original values
   var authorsCollectionEntry = entry.Collection(x => x.AuthorBooks);
   var currentAuthorIds = authorsCollectionEntry.CurrentValue.Select(x => x.AuthorId).ToList();
   var originalAuthorIds = ?????;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at all the tracked AuthorBook entities and finding ones whose   Author, or AuthorID OrignialValue matches the ID of `entry`?

Comment: I haven't tried that but if I go that way, it will tell me which AuthorBook are tracked but not which AuthorBook are acutally linked to my Book or was linked to my book. Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Looking to get the Original Navigation Property values and the new navigation property values

Comment: @Pierre, I have'nt found a way to do it. I had to rethink everything to bypass this limitation.

Comment: @AlexandreJobin, Got it to work by loading the navigation property using the context: `context.Entry(entry.Entity).Reference(x => x.Promotion).Load();` then afterwards have the values. To get the current and original values from the reference property, had to first create temp vars and clone the current/original values, set the original values as current values on the `entity` then load the reference to get the original values, set the `Entity` current values back to the cloned current values, load the reference to get its current values, done. You can temp modify state as well for Add/Delete

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the reference properties in the context as well as its original values:

```
var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<Book>()
                .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .ToList();

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    // If it is Added/Deleted, you can't get the OriginalValues/CurrentValues respectively.
    // So make it Modified for the meanwhile.
    var tempState = entry.State;
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    
    // Clone the Entity values (the original ID, Current ID of the navigation
    var currentValues = Entry(entry.Entity).CurrentValues.Clone();
    var originalValues = Entry(entry.Entity).OriginalValues.Clone();
    
    // Set the Entity values to the OriginalValues and load the reference
    Entry(entry.Entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(originalValues);
    Entry(entry.Entity).Reference(x => x.Promotion).Load();
    
    // Store the Original Reference value in a variable
    var promotionReferenceEntryOriginalValue = entry.Reference(x => x.Promotion).CurrentValue;
    
    // Set the Entity values back to CurrentValues and load the reference
    Entry(entry.Entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(currentValues);
    Entry(entry.Entity).Reference(x => x.Promotion).Load();
    
    // Store the Current Reference value in a variable
    var promotionReferenceEntryCurrentValue = entry.Reference(x => x.Promotion).CurrentValue;
    
    // Set the Entry State back to its original State Added/Modified/Deleted
    entry.State = tempState;
    
    // read the entity current & original values 
    var currentTitleValue = entry.Property(x => x.Title).CurrentValue;
    var originalTitleValue = entry.Property(x => x.Title).OriginalValue;

    // read the reference object current & original values
    //var promotionReferenceEntry = entry.Reference(x => x.Promotion);
    var currentPromotionPriceValue = promotionReferenceEntryCurrentValue.Price; // promotionReferenceEntry.TargetEntry.Property(x => x.Price).CurrentValue;
    var originalPromotionPriceValue = promotionReferenceEntryOriginalValue.Price; // promotionReferenceEntry.TargetEntry.Property(x => x.Price).OriginalValue;
}
```

To make it dynamic, remove the type `<Book>` from `ChangeTracker.Entries<Book>()` and loop though the `entry.Entity` properties inside the `foreach (var entry in entries)` loop:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
    //Do the loads here...
    //Get the values
}
```

Check if it is a navigation reference or a collection reference by trying to access it using extra methods and check if it is null or not, not null means it is a valid property to try and `load()` it:

```
private DbPropertyEntry GetProperty(DbEntityEntry entry, string propertyName)
{
    try
    {
        return entry.Property(propertyName);
    }
    catch { return null; }
}

private DbReferenceEntry GetReference(DbEntityEntry entry, string propertyName)
{
    try
    {
        return entry.Reference(propertyName);
    }
    catch { return null; }
}

private DbCollectionEntry GetCollection(DbEntityEntry entry, string propertyName)
{
    try
    {
        return entry.Collection(propertyName);
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```